# Ideals and Centers in an Lie Algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, lie-algebras

To my understanding, a Lie Algebra $A$ is a misnomer as $A$ is any set not necessary a ring. But rather, a Lie Algebra is specifically a vector space $A$  where the multiplicative map $A \times A \to A$ is the Lie Bracket. Actually from what I am reading, the product $[X,Y]$ is not explicitly defined unless we force $[X,Y] = XY - YX \in A$ where henceforth require $A$ to be associative.

Okay so onto my main question. Ideals $I$ and centers $C$ in a Lie Algebra $A$ are defined by the bracket $$[X,i ] \in I,\forall i \in I, \forall X \in A$$ and $$[X, Y] = 0, \forall X,Y \in A$$

Can someone explain how we can define ideals in a Lie Algebra like this? Because $A$ is not actually a ring. Is the bracket a form of the absorption $XI \subset I$ except where the product is defined by the bracket like I earlier suspected? And the implication that centre is defined in the "ring" structure? because we can equally define a center for the additive group in $A$ as it is a module.

Comment: Not exactly. To define an ideal $I$ of a Lie Algebra what you need is that $I$ is a vector space, and the bracket $[X,Y]\in I$ for every $Y\in I$ and $X\in A$ (I now think that's what you meant, but you can write it better).
By the way, you don't need a ring to define ideal-like things. You can define ideals in boolean algebras, for example.

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper, sorry I left that out. But yes we do require $I$ to be a vector subspace of $A$. But is the rest and my preliminary writing correct.

Comment: Hm I don't know much if anything about boolean algebras and I am not sure if I want to read too much into it as it may stray me afar from what I am focusing on.

Comment: Yes, the definition works. But as I was saying, you don't require a full ring structure to define things which behave like ideals, and then call them like that (It's just that in a ring they are easier to manage in most cases). You can define it in boolean algebras, or even in lattices (See Kelley's General Topology, page 80, for an example).

Comment: You don't need the boolean algebras, just remember that you don't need the full ring structure for something like an ideal to exist and work. In particular, a Lie Algebra.

Comment: And for the center, you can see it as a generalization of the center of a ring.  But in this case, it becomes an ideal.

Comment: So I missed something in this conversation, why do we call it an Ideal here then? Since it doesn't require a ring structure to define an ideal, I am guessing all of my thoughts regarding $[.]$ the bracket as the "multiplicative-operation" is meaningless then? I mean I just equate the two because it seemed convenient and natural.

Comment: We call them ideals because they're an analogous notion to ideals in rings even if the structure is not a ring anymore. Your thoughts about taking the bracket as some multiplication are fine, at least on the definition of ideals in the Lie Algebra. 
In the center you don't take it as a multiplication, but as a generalization of the commutator $XY-YX$ which can be used to define the center in a ring. But all in all, it's as you say. The definition is because it's convenient and naturald to define things that way.

Comment: Is my understanding that the Lie Algebra misnomer correct?

Comment: No, the term algebra is not a misnomer here. It just happens that in many contexts people use the term "algebra" to mean "associative algebra", but that does not mean everyone else has to. Ideals have that name because they are the things we can quotient by.